# Question on population columns in lists

Tags: list

I have a list and I what I want is for when a user clicks 'Add new item', they will be presented with two fields.

The first a drop down containing say 3 items.

The second field I want to be populated by data depending on the choice of the first field.

So the logic would be something like 'if user chooses item 1 in column one, present them the following items to choose from in column two'. This way I can nicely restrict how they enter data.

Would I need to use InfoPath for such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need Infopath, you can do it even with JavaScript/JQuery. Read the following blogs and you may get some ideas.

http://www.markrackley.net/2014/05/20/cascading-drop-down-lists-in-sharepoint-office-365-using-rest/

or

[Cascade drop down lists in SharePoint 2013 using jQuery, REST and AJAX](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119902/cascade-drop-down-lists-in-sharepoint-2013-using-jquery-rest-and-ajax)

or

http://nagendra-gunaga.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-implement-cascaded-dropdown-list.html

The first reference worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use inform path.

Here is the idea to start of , for SP 2013

the following link gives you ample methods how to fulfill your requirement

[CSR JS Links on List views](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)